# Parameter value is not getting resolved

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am using below command and its working fine:

```
zcat abc.dat.gz | awk -F\| 'NF==102{print NR,$0}'
```

but when I am using above command in script as below then `temp_var2` is not getting resolved.

```
zcat "$1" | awk -F "$2" 'NF==$temp_var2{print NR,$0}'
```

Here, `$1` and `$2` are parameters which are passed while running script and `temp_var2` I am creating inside which is getting assigned as numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because variables are not expanded within single-quotes. `awk` has a built-in workaround for this in the `-v` switch. Try this:

```
zcat "$1" | awk -F "$2" -v var="$temp_var2" ' NF == var { print NR, $0 }'
```